# Check all checkboxes inside an iframe (when inviting guests to a facebook event)

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to check all checkboxes when inviting guests to a facebook event. Facebook has changed something i think beacuse i usually used this code and now it is not working:

```
var elms=document.getElementsByName("checkableitems[]");
var lunghezza = elms.length;
for (i=0;i<lunghezza ;i++){if (elms[i].type="checkbox" )elms[i].click()};
```

I discovered that the modal windows to invite guests is inside an iframe but i can't checkboxes inside it!

I've used

```
jQuery('iframe#iframe_sbx_id').find('input[type=checkbox]').click()
```

but it doesn't work because find() returns an empty set. Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Is it a modal dialog or just an iframe within the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to access the content of the iframe, but because it's on another domain, it won't work:

> The .contents() method can also be
>   used to get the content document of an
>   iframe, if the iframe is on the same
>   domain as the main page.

Comment: Yes you are right: i get "Error: Permission denied to access property 'ownerDocument'" if i try it. Have you got any idea on how to bypass this?

Comment: There's no way to access an iframe content from another domain. Otherwise you could do terrible things (get the user's friend list, read his mails, etc.). I don't know what Facebook provides. Maybe there's another way (through an API for example).

Comment: Ok, there is nothing to do, so i accept your answer!Thnx for your hekp!